# Can someone tell me how do I create a class in sqldeveloper?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Recently I'm learning sql by myself and it's really tough to me.

For example I'd like create a sql class called XXX and also I'd like add some attributes into the class like country, population, etc.

So how do I write the code? Can anyone show me how to do that with a simple example?

I would fully appreciate for that.

Comment: @ Arun Palanisamy ,I don know sir lol that's why I get confused, I learned sql in the online course and the teacher mentioned that we can create a class and the class can have multiple attributes.

Comment: There are no "classes" in SQL. Only tables. Oracle's PL/SQL supports creating "object types" which is probably the closest to a class you can get. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Type` like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MYCLASS AS OBJECT 
(Country varchar2(30), 
 Population varchar2(30)
); 
/     

CREATE TABLE MYTABLE of MYCLASS;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create table like this:

```
create table your_class_table
(
country varchar2(2000 char),
population number
)
```

then you can insert data into it then select.

Comment: Thanks you sir, but how do I create class and declare multiple attributes to it?